# Mutlithreaded server with producer consumer threads

Tags: c, multithreading, server, producer-consumer

I have the following code of a server:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "utils.h"
#include "kissdb.h"

#define MY_PORT                 6767
#define BUF_SIZE                1160
#define KEY_SIZE                 128
#define HASH_SIZE               1024
#define VALUE_SIZE              1024
#define MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS   10

// Definition of the operation type.
typedef enum operation {
  PUT,
  GET
} Operation; 

// Definition of the request.
typedef struct request {
  Operation operation;
  char key[KEY_SIZE];  
  char value[VALUE_SIZE];
} Request;

// Definition of the database.
KISSDB *db = NULL;

/**
 * @name parse_request - Parses a received message and generates a new request.
 * @param buffer: A pointer to the received message.
 *
 * @return Initialized request on Success. NULL on Error.
 */
Request *parse_request(char *buffer) {
  char *token = NULL;
  Request *req = NULL;
  
  // Check arguments.
  if (!buffer)
    return NULL;
  
  // Prepare the request.
  req = (Request *) malloc(sizeof(Request));
  memset(req->key, 0, KEY_SIZE);
  memset(req->value, 0, VALUE_SIZE);

  // Extract the operation type.
  token = strtok(buffer, ":");    
  if (!strcmp(token, "PUT")) {
    req->operation = PUT;
  } else if (!strcmp(token, "GET")) {
    req->operation = GET;
  } else {
    free(req);
    return NULL;
  }
  
  // Extract the key.
  token = strtok(NULL, ":");
  if (token) {
    strncpy(req->key, token, KEY_SIZE);
  } else {
    free(req);
    return NULL;
  }
  
  // Extract the value.
  token = strtok(NULL, ":");
  if (token) {
    strncpy(req->value, token, VALUE_SIZE);
  } else if (req->operation == PUT) {
    free(req);
    return NULL;
  }
  return req;
}

/*
 * @name process_request - Process a client request.
 * @param socket_fd: The accept descriptor.
 *
 * @return
 */
void process_request(const int socket_fd) {
  char response_str[BUF_SIZE], request_str[BUF_SIZE];
    int numbytes = 0;
    Request *request = NULL;

    // Clean buffers.
    memset(response_str, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    memset(request_str, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    
    // receive message.
    numbytes = read_str_from_socket(socket_fd, request_str, BUF_SIZE);
    
    // parse the request.
    if (numbytes) {
      request = parse_request(request_str);
      if (request) {
        switch (request->operation) {
          case GET:
            // Read the given key from the database.
            if (KISSDB_get(db, request->key, request->value))
              sprintf(response_str, "GET ERROR\n");
            else
              sprintf(response_str, "GET OK: %s\n", request->value);
            break;
          case PUT:
            // Write the given key/value pair to the database.
            if (KISSDB_put(db, request->key, request->value)) 
              sprintf(response_str, "PUT ERROR\n");
            else
              sprintf(response_str, "PUT OK\n");
            break;
          default:
            // Unsupported operation.
            sprintf(response_str, "UNKOWN OPERATION\n");
        }
        // Reply to the client.
        write_str_to_socket(socket_fd, response_str, strlen(response_str));
        if (request)
          free(request);
        request = NULL;
        return;
      }
    }
    // Send an Error reply to the client.
    sprintf(response_str, "FORMAT ERROR\n");
    write_str_to_socket(socket_fd, response_str, strlen(response_str));
}

/*
 * @name main - The main routine.
 *
 * @return 0 on success, 1 on error.
 */
int main() {

  int socket_fd,              // listen on this socket for new connections
      new_fd;                 // use this socket to service a new connection
  socklen_t clen;
  struct sockaddr_in server_addr,  // my address information
                     client_addr;  // connector's address information

  // create socket
  if ((socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    ERROR("socket()");

  // Ignore the SIGPIPE signal in order to not crash when a
  // client closes the connection unexpectedly.
  signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
  
  // create socket adress of server (type, IP-adress and port number)
  bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    // any local interface
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
  
  // bind socket to address
  if (bind(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
    ERROR("bind()");
  
  // start listening to socket for incoming connections
  listen(socket_fd, MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS);
  fprintf(stderr, "(Info) main: Listening for new connections on port %d ...\n", MY_PORT);
  clen = sizeof(client_addr);

  // Allocate memory for the database.
  if (!(db = (KISSDB *)malloc(sizeof(KISSDB)))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "(Error) main: Cannot allocate memory for the database.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  
  // Open the database.
  if (KISSDB_open(db, "mydb.db", KISSDB_OPEN_MODE_RWCREAT, HASH_SIZE, KEY_SIZE, VALUE_SIZE)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "(Error) main: Cannot open the database.\n");
    return 1;
  }

  // main loop: wait for new connection/requests
  while (1) { 
    // wait for incoming connection
    if ((new_fd = accept(socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clen)) == -1) {
      ERROR("accept()");
    }
    
    // got connection, serve request
    fprintf(stderr, "(Info) main: Got connection from '%s'\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));
    
    process_request(new_fd);
    close(new_fd);
  }  

  // Destroy the database.
  // Close the database.
  KISSDB_close(db);

  // Free memory.
  if (db)
    free(db);
  db = NULL;

  return 0; 
}
```

which handles a database (KISSDB here) that stores and prints values based on a key . I want to modify it , adding `threads` , producer and consumer ones. Producer thread should accept clients request and consumer thread execute it. I thought about putting all socket functions in a `*producer()` function that would handle them and let the consumer handle '`process_request()` as it is . In main the threads are being created and called . It doesn't seem to run though , it compiles okay , but when executing `./client -a localhost -i 1 -p` to start the `client` in the terminal , the program doesn't stop. I suspect the

pthread_create(&consumer_thread,NULL,process_request,(void*)&thread_args.new_fd);

is the problem. When I try to run the server , I get :

```
(Info) main: Listening for new connections on port 6767 ...
Error in read_from_socket(). Cause: Bad file descriptor
```

See what I've tried :

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <inttypes.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <sys/time.h>   
#include <sys/resource.h> 

#include<pthread.h>
pthread_mutex_t mymutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER; 
pthread_mutex_t c = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "utils.h"
#include "kissdb.h"

//we have to use it


#define MY_PORT                 6767
#define BUF_SIZE                1160
#define KEY_SIZE                 128
#define HASH_SIZE               1024
#define VALUE_SIZE              1024
#define MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS   10


// =======================================
//struct timespec {                 // INCLUDE IN <time.h> ?                                                                    
 //   time_t   tv_sec;        /* seconds */                                                             
//    long     tv_nsec;       /* nanoseconds */                                                         
//};   

/*
int socket_fd,              // listen on this socket for new connections
      new_fd;                 // use this socket to service a new connection
socklen_t clen;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr,  // my address information
                   client_addr;  // connector's address information
*/

struct data {
   int   socket_fd;              // listen on this socket for new connections
   int   new_fd;                 // use this socket to service a new connection
};


// Definition of the operation type.
typedef enum operation {
  PUT,
  GET
} Operation; 

// Definition of the request.
typedef struct request {
  Operation operation;
  char key[KEY_SIZE];  
  char value[VALUE_SIZE];
} Request;

// Definition of the database.
KISSDB *db = NULL;

/**
 * @name parse_request - Parses a received message and generates a new request.
 * @param buffer: A pointer to the received message.
 *
 * @return Initialized request on Success. NULL on Error.
 */
Request *parse_request(char *buffer) {
  char *token = NULL;
  Request *req = NULL;
  
  // Check arguments.
  if (!buffer)
    return NULL;
  
  // Prepare the request.
  req = (Request *) malloc(sizeof(Request));
  memset(req->key, 0, KEY_SIZE);
  memset(req->value, 0, VALUE_SIZE);

  // Extract the operation type.
  token = strtok(buffer, ":");    
  if (!strcmp(token, "PUT")) {
    req->operation = PUT;
  } else if (!strcmp(token, "GET")) {
    req->operation = GET;
  } else {
    free(req);
    return NULL;
  }
  
  // Extract the key.
  token = strtok(NULL, ":");
  if (token) {
    strncpy(req->key, token, KEY_SIZE);
  } else {
    free(req);
    return NULL;
  }
  
  // Extract the value.
  token = strtok(NULL, ":");
  if (token) {
    strncpy(req->value, token, VALUE_SIZE);
  } else if (req->operation == PUT) {
    free(req);
    return NULL;
  }
  return req;
}

/*
 * @name process_request - Process a client request.
 * @param socket_fd: The accept descriptor.
 *
 * @return
 */

//for consumer
void *process_request(void * socket_fd) {
  char response_str[BUF_SIZE], request_str[BUF_SIZE];
    int numbytes = 0;
    Request *request = NULL;

    // Clean buffers.
    memset(response_str, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    memset(request_str, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    
    // receive message.
    numbytes = read_str_from_socket(socket_fd, request_str, BUF_SIZE);
    
    // parse the request.
    if (numbytes) {
      request = parse_request(request_str);
      if (request) {
        switch (request->operation) {
          case GET:
            // Read the given key from the database.
            if (KISSDB_get(db, request->key, request->value))
              sprintf(response_str, "GET ERROR\n");
            else
              sprintf(response_str, "GET OK: %s\n", request->value);
            break;
          case PUT:
            // Write the given key/value pair to the database.
            if (KISSDB_put(db, request->key, request->value)) 
              sprintf(response_str, "PUT ERROR\n");
            else
              sprintf(response_str, "PUT OK\n");
            break;
          default:
            // Unsupported operation.
            sprintf(response_str, "UNKOWN OPERATION\n");
        }
        // Reply to the client.
        write_str_to_socket(socket_fd, response_str, strlen(response_str));
        if (request)
          free(request);
        request = NULL;
        return;
      }
    }
    // Send an Error reply to the client.
    sprintf(response_str, "FORMAT ERROR\n");
    write_str_to_socket(socket_fd, response_str, strlen(response_str));
}


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void *producer(void *arg) {
//   int socket_fd,              // listen on this socket for new connections
//      new_fd;                 // use this socket to service a new connection
   socklen_t clen;
   struct sockaddr_in server_addr,  // my address information
                      client_addr;  // connector's address information

   struct data *d = (struct data *) arg;


   // create socket
   if ((d->socket_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
    ERROR("socket()");

   // Ignore the SIGPIPE signal in order to not crash when a
   // client closes the connection unexpectedly.
   signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
  
   // create socket adress of server (type, IP-adress and port number)
   bzero(&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
   server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);    // any local interface
   server_addr.sin_port = htons(MY_PORT);
  
   // bind socket to address
   if (bind(d->socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
      ERROR("bind()");
  
   // start listening to socket for incoming connections
   listen(d->socket_fd, MAX_PENDING_CONNECTIONS);
   fprintf(stderr, "(Info) main: Listening for new connections on port %d ...\n", MY_PORT);
   clen = sizeof(client_addr);  


   // wait for incoming connection                          EDW 8A KANOUME TA THREADS ? 
   if ((d->new_fd = accept(d->socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clen)) == -1) { // to client_socket pou 8a peira3oume
      ERROR("accept()");
    }
    
    //clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &spec); 
    
    //s  = spec.tv_sec;
    //ms = spec.tv_nsec;    

    //fprintf(stderr, "Current time: %li . %03ld seconds since the connection\n",(long)s, ms);
           
            
    // got connection, serve request
    fprintf(stderr, "(Info) main: Got connection from '%s'\n", inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr));

}



/*
 * @name main - The main routine.
 *
 * @return 0 on success, 1 on error.
 */
int main() {

   long            ms; // Milliseconds
   time_t          s;  // Seconds

   struct timespec spec;
   struct data thread_args;

  

  // Allocate memory for the database.
  if (!(db = (KISSDB *)malloc(sizeof(KISSDB)))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "(Error) main: Cannot allocate memory for the database.\n");
    return 1;
  }
  
  // Open the database.
  if (KISSDB_open(db, "mydb.db", KISSDB_OPEN_MODE_RWCREAT, HASH_SIZE, KEY_SIZE, VALUE_SIZE)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "(Error) main: Cannot open the database.\n");
    return 1;
  }


  pthread_t producer_thread;    

  pthread_create(&producer_thread,NULL,producer,(void *) &thread_args); 

  // main loop: wait for new connection/requests
  while (1) { 
    
    
    //process_request(new_fd); // nai !
        
    /*teo's new code , for (i) part of project */   
    pthread_t consumer_thread;  

    pthread_create(&consumer_thread,NULL,process_request,(void*)&thread_args.new_fd);

    pthread_join(consumer_thread,NULL); // necessary 

        

    /*      */ 

    //close(new_fd);
  }  

  // Destroy the database.
  // Close the database.
  KISSDB_close(db);

  // Free memory.
  if (db)
    free(db);
  db = NULL;

  

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: *the server doesn't seem to run* - that's rather vague. Which part? It crashes on startup? It doesn't accept connections?

Comment: I see you’re passing a pointer to `new_fd` as the thread argument. You should probably *cast* `new_fd` to `void*` to pass it, and cast it back to `int` in the thread function to get the original value.

Comment: Alternatively, you *can* pass the pointer, but then you need to make sure the object it points to exists for as long as the thread may access it. For example, you can `malloc` a struct, fill it, pass a pointer to the new thread, and let that thread `free` it after using.